# cocoa:webView which have hyperlinks to add the ` target = " _blank "` can not be opened

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

webView which have hyperlinks to add the `target = " _blank "` can not be opened.

I developing a webview-like application, but i have one problem. How to open link in new window in current application - not in safari?

Thanks for help.

[image]

@Rob Keniger  The code is not running.why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an object as the `UIDelegate` of your `WebView` and in that object implement the [`webView:createWebViewWithRequest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915-CHDDCJCA) method.

In your implementation of that method, you need to open a new window containing a separate `WebView` and then tell its `mainFrame` to load the `URLRequest` passed as a parameter to the method.

**Update:**

I've looked at your code. You need to assign an object as the web view's `UIDelegate`, so add a `[webView setUIDelegate:self]` line into `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

A very simple example of how to implement the delegate would be:

```
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSUInteger windowStyleMask =    NSClosableWindowMask | 
                                    NSMiniaturizableWindowMask |
                                    NSResizableWindowMask |
                                    NSTitledWindowMask;
    NSWindow* webWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 600) styleMask:windowStyleMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    WebView* newWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:[webWindow contentRectForFrameRect:webWindow.frame]];
    [newWebView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [webWindow setContentView:newWebView];
    [webWindow center];
    [webWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [[newWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
    return newWebView;
}
```

Comment: `[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];`Use javascript on the page, delete `"_blank"`。This method is not good.

Comment: This is my code downloaded.http://code.google.com/p/macdesktop/downloads/list       Thank you for help me .

Comment: I know，Thank you.  @Rob Keniger You are my spiritual pillar.Thanks help me.